# how pass dynamic attribute to custom validator

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, custom-validators

I'm building a custom validator as a directive for a component, and I am trying to pass an attribute, but I am not being able to retrieve the value, just the string of the method I am calling.

Part of the code is:

directive:

```
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
 link: (scope, element, attributes, ngModel) => {
            const myAttrib = attributes.myValidation ;
            console.log(myAttrib);
            ...
    }
```

component:

```
my-validation="$ctrl.getmyAtt()"
```

controller:

```
getmyAtt() { return "blah"; }
```

so in the console I get "$ctrl.getmyAtt()" instead of blah.
How do I get blah?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to inject the `$parse` service and use it to get the actual value being passed in.

```
$parse(attributes.myValidation)($scope);
```

`$parse` documentation [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$parse).

edit: Actually, that won't work for your callback parameter. Instead you'll want to store that string and run it as javascript at a later time when the callback needs to be run.

```
var returnValue = scope.$eval(myAttrib);
```